# SOAP API calls to retrieve the SFMC users who do not have SSO enabled

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

Can anyone pass me on few links or the code snippet for retrieving the users in Marketing cloud account whose SSO is enabled using SOAP API calls

Comment: Have you tried it?  If so, please update your question with what you have.

Answer (score 3):

The SsoIdentities property of the [AccountUser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/accountuser.html) object is not retrievable, unfortunately.

Also, I wouldn't 100% trust the official documentation or the Describe results.  I've found that doing a retrieve on all of the properties (retrievable or not) will give you a list of the ones that are *actually* not retrievable.

**Request**

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Create</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{soapEndpoint}}</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <DefinitionRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <DescribeRequests>
                <ClientIDs>
                    <ID>{{mid}}</ID>
                </ClientIDs>
                <ObjectDefinitionRequest>
                    <ObjectType>AccountUser</ObjectType>
                </ObjectDefinitionRequest>
            </DescribeRequests>
        </DefinitionRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**Response**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wsa:Action>CreateResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:f87e08a4-e017-4809-9688-52edaa293174</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:aaa3e226-21b5-40f3-ad38-8acbf3782e66</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-dd592f13-4598-43a4-acfd-709d94c7ea8f">
                <wsu:Created>2022-05-26T12:23:20Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2022-05-26T12:28:20Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <DefinitionResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <ObjectDefinition>
                <ObjectType>AccountUser</ObjectType>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>ID</Name>
                    <DataType>Int32</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>CreatedDate</Name>
                    <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>ModifiedDate</Name>
                    <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>Client.ID</Name>
                    <DataType>Int32</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>AccountUserID</Name>
                    <DataType>Int32</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>UserID</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>128</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>Name</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>50</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>Email</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>254</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>MustChangePassword</Name>
                    <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>ActiveFlag</Name>
                    <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>ChallengePhrase</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>128</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>ChallengeAnswer</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>64</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>IsAPIUser</Name>
                    <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>NotificationEmailAddress</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>254</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>Client.PartnerClientKey</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>64</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>Password</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>227</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>IsSendable</Name>
                    <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>Locale.LocaleCode</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>5</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>TimeZone.ID</Name>
                    <DataType>Int32</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>TimeZone.Name</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>128</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>CustomerKey</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>36</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>SalesForceID</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>18</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>DefaultBusinessUnit</Name>
                    <DataType>Int32</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>LanguageLocale.LocaleCode</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>40</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>Client.ModifiedBy</Name>
                    <DataType>Int32</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>UserPermissions</Name>
                    <DataType>UserAccess[]</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>Delete</Name>
                    <DataType>Int32</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>LastSuccessfulLogin</Name>
                    <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>IsLocked</Name>
                    <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>Unlock</Name>
                    <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>BusinessUnit</Name>
                    <DataType>Int32</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>DefaultApplication</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>Locale</Name>
                    <DataType>Locale</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>TimeZone</Name>
                    <DataType>TimeZone</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>DefaultBusinessUnitObject</Name>
                    <DataType>BusinessUnit</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>AssociatedBusinessUnits</Name>
                    <DataType>BusinessUnit[]</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>Roles</Name>
                    <DataType>Role[]</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>LanguageLocale</Name>
                    <DataType>Locale</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>Applications</Name>
                    <DataType>Manage_Application[]</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>ProvideIMHAccess</Name>
                    <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>FederationObject</Name>
                    <DataType>Federation</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>SsoIdentities</Name>
                    <DataType>SsoIdentity[]</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>BusinessUnitAssignmentConfiguration</Name>
                    <DataType>BusinessUnitAssignmentConfiguration</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>Client</Name>
                    <DataType>ClientID</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>PartnerKey</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>PartnerProperties</Name>
                    <DataType>APIProperty[]</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>ObjectID</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>Owner</Name>
                    <DataType>Owner</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>CorrelationID</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>ObjectState</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>IsPlatformObject</Name>
                    <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
            </ObjectDefinition>
            <RequestID>8866ed55-a2ec-4b34-b23e-61cb29546eed</RequestID>
        </DefinitionResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```